# getting java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error in groovy

Tags: java, arrays, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am getting `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` error in groovy while running below code.

```
stage('Calculate Opatch size') { 
        def files = findFiles(glob: '${BuildPathPublishRoot}\\30293915.*.zip') 
        echo """${files[0].length}"""
}
```

Below is the log:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgmimpl.arrays.ObjectArrayGetAtMetaMethod.invoke(ObjectArrayGetAtMetaMethod.java:41)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1225)
```

Can someone help me to understand the error and fix it.

Comment: `files` is empty , so, `files[0]` throws exception

Comment: Change single quote to double quote which conduct `BuildPathPublishRoot` compiled to real value in `'${BuildPathPublishRoot}\\30293915.*.zip'`

Comment: this worked for me. Thanks                                                                                              
           ```{ 
  def files
  dir("${BuildPathPublishRoot}") {
  files = findFiles(glob: '**', includes: '.zip')
 // echo """${files[0].length}"""
  Size1 = """${files[0].length}"""
  
  echo Size1
  
  }```

Answer (score 0):

The only array index access you do is in `files[0]`. As the Exception tells you, your array has the length 0, hence you get the error. Maybe add an empty check before accessing it?

Answer (score 0):

Your findFiles does not return an array, so there is no files[0]!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's files[0]. But I got this error message in another context, when using Multibranch pipeline from our Jenkinsfile template that defaults to traditional pipeline, and has

```
BUILD_ENV = [master: 'prod', develop: 'stg'].get(env.GIT_BRANCH.split('/')[1], 'dev')
```

Over here the error message comes from env.GIT_BRANCH which is empty/null in multibranch pipeline.

On a multibranch pipeline the same row is:

```
BUILD_ENV = [master: 'prod', develop: 'stg'].get(env.BRANCH_NAME, 'dev')
```